# Why does this sparql query returns duplicates (and how to avoid that?)

Tags: sparql

I'm confused about some particular behavior of sparql.

Let's assume some test-data formatted as n-triples like this:

```
<s1> <t> <t1> .
<s1> <t> <t2> .
<s1> <p> <o> .
<s2> <p> <o> .
```

What I want to have returned is *of the subjects which have a property **t** all their triples in which they occur*. For example with this test data I would like to have returned:

```
<s1> <t> <t1> .
<s1> <t> <t2> .
<s1> <p> <o> .
```

but not the triple with **s2** since it doesn't have a property **t** defined anywhere.

Now, issuing a query like this:

```
select * where { ?s ?p ?o . ?s <t> [] }
```

returns

```
| s1 | p | o  |
| s1 | t | t1 |
| s1 | t | t2 |
| s1 | p | o  |
| s1 | t | t1 |
| s1 | t | t2 |
```

Why are there duplicates generated and how can this be avoided?

Comment: Well, have you ever heard about the keyword [`DISTINCT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#sparqlDistinct)?

Comment: I do and I used it to filter the duplicates out, but I feel like there should be a better way which involves not producing the duplicates in the first place. Hence my question.

Comment: I don'T understand why as this is task of the query optimizer...but here is an alternative: `select * where { ?s ?p ?o . filter(exists{ ?s <t> [] } ) }`

Comment: This query works like a charm and seems pretty efficient too. Thanks for providing it. But furthermore do you know the cause / design decision behind the duplicated results of my initial query? I'd be also curious about knowing why sparql was designed in such a way since that seems rather not intuitive to me at a first glance.

Comment: The "problem" is that a set of triple patterns denote the logical `AND` which is technically a join on matching variables (otherwise cartesian product). You have two triple patterns, take a sheet of paper and write down all the combinations - this helps to understand this.

Comment: So the two clauses in the 'where' part evaluate the variables against their individual values rather than against triples? And then it matches all the combinations with the substituted values? Coming from SQL I would assume that this works rather on a 'row' rather than on the 'values'. Well, but having these substitutions and their combinations elaborated on paper did indeed help. Thank you a lot!